# what is the equal method of opencv pyrDown() in to javacv?

Tags: java, c++, opencv

Please can some one explain the javacv method for the pyrDown() method. I'm trying to convert [opencv code](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/squares.cpp) in to javacv in there i found this method. 
This is the code segment

```
51    Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
52
53    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
54    pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
```

Please can some one explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this like this

```
CvSize sz = cvSize(src.width() & -2, src.height() & -2);
```

and the work that you trying to do is already done so I believe this could be great help to provide that javacv code for the square detection. this is the link.

http://pastie.org/3959600

try to go through this.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much on your quick reply actually it is great help to understand that opencv code.